# How to set Kafka Streams properties in code when using Spring Cloud Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, stream

In Spring Boot with Kafka, I can set properties for a ConsumerFactory as follows:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, EnrichedOrder> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "barnwaldo");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, EnrichedOrderDeserializer.class);

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, EnrichedOrder> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, EnrichedOrder> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

}

Using Kafka Streams, I can set properties in code as follows:

```
    final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-lambda-example");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-lambda-example-client");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10 * 1000);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
    final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);
```

When working with Spring Cloud Streams and Kafka Streams, all properties appear to entered only via application.properties or application.yml files in the resource folder such as

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings:
    output:
        contentType: application/json
        destination: data2
    input:
        contentType: application/json
        destination: data1
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams:
    binder:
      brokers: localhost
      configuration:
        commit.interval.ms: 1000
        default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
        default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    bindings.input.consumer:
        applicationId: data-tester
```

Is there a way to include properties in a HashMap or a Properties when using  Spring Cloud Streams with Kafka Streams.

Perhaps this can be done somehow with the KafkaMessageChannelBinder or by extending the AbstractMessageChannelBinder - see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/7355ada4613ad50fe95430f1859d4ea65f004be1/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java.

I can find no documentation referring to this; any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default it has support at the binder level where the properties should be prefixed with `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.` literal

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.M3/multi/multi__apache_kafka_streams_binder.html#_configuration_options_3

If you see the `KafkaStreamsBinderSupportAutoConfiguration` class, you can see the bean configuration, that reads from yaml properties and set to kafka streams.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/KafkaStreamsBinderSupportAutoConfiguration.java